# Split string at # in C

Tags: c, string, split

I have a string like this:

```
char *message = "12#34#56#78#90"
```

I want to get:

```
a = "12"
b = "34"
c = "56"
d = "78"
d = "90"
```

Who can give me a good method?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/c-how-to-split-a-string shows you how to do this in C++

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`strtok()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/). Note that even though that is C++ documentation, the function is also present in C. Take special note to use `NULL` in subsequent calls to get the next token.

```
char label = 'a';
char *token = strtok(message, "#");
while (token != NULL) {
  printf("%c = \"%s\"\n", label++, token);
  token = strtok(NULL, "#");
}
```

Outputs:

```
a = "12"
b = "34"
c = "56"
d = "78"
e = "90"
```

See http://ideone.com/xk1uO

Comment: Thanks! one more question, if I want to get "1234567890", how to do this?

Comment: I mean can i get "1234567890" from "12#34#56#78#90" directly?

Comment: @why This should really be a separate question. SO is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.

Comment: @why:  Maintain two pointers into the string.  The destination pointer is initialized to the first '#'.  The source pointer to the first digit after the first '#'.  When the source pointer finds a valid digit, copy the digit to `*destination++`.  Advance source pointer to next digit, repeat until source pointer hits end of string.  Assign '\0' to destination pointer.

Answer (score 2):

The strtok function in the standard library does this, you can loop over the string extracting all the tokens.

Answer (score 1):

strtok_r its like strtok but safer. strtok is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Let's use strsep - no need to depend on a static variable by passing in NULL.

```
char *string; // It holds "12#34#56"; (cannot be string literal)
char *token = NULL;

while ((token = strsep(&string, "#"))) {
   printf("%s\n", token);
}
```